# How can I efficiently handle large CSV files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, size

I have a CSV file with millions of rows and columns that I need to process in Python. However, when I try to load it into memory using pandas or csv modules, my program becomes extremely slow and memory-intensive.

What are some efficient techniques or libraries that I can use to handle such large CSV files in Python? I have heard about chunking and streaming the data, but I am not sure how to implement them. Can you provide some code examples or point me to some helpful resources?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `Dask`: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html (or `modin[dask]` or `pyspark`). What is the size of your file? What do you want to do with data?

Comment: The standard csv module will always be more memory efficient and faster than any of the big data-processing libs. Here's how to process your large CSV by streaming rows from reader to writer: https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/ac4acc19274d9fc40bfc2f98d05c3ae8.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/), which is *really* fast (if you can stay in memory). e.g. from their docs:

```
import polars as pl

q = (
    pl.scan_csv("iris.csv")
    .filter(pl.col("sepal_length") > 5)
    .groupby("species")
    .agg(pl.all().sum())
)

df = q.collect()
```